# Python Errors "NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to write a script that pulls 2 CSV's files named PopChange.csv, and Housing.csv, using pandas on python. I am making the selection of options to choose from, but keep getting this error message. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Project I'm trying to do which gives the options of choices and pulls the CSV files to print or the results in a histogram:

```
***************** Welcome to the Python Data Analysis App**********

Select the file you want to analyze:
1. Population Data
2. Housing Data
3. Exit the Program

1

You have entered Population Data.

Select the Column you want to analyze:

a. Pop Apr 1

b. Pop Jul 1

c. Change Pop

d. Exit Column

a

You selected Pop Apr 1

The statistics for this column are:

Count = 10000
Mean = 32.5
Standard Deviation = 4.5
Min = 53.2
Max = 12.5
The Histogram of this column is now displayed.

Select the Column you want to analyze:
a. Pop Apr 1
b. Pop Jul 1
c. Change Pop
d. Exit Column 

d
You selected to exit the column menu

Select the file you want to analyze:

1. Population Data

2. Housing Data

3. Exit the Program

3

*************** Thanks for using the Data Analysis App**********
```

Below is my code which I'm having the issues with and not fully understanding why. I'm using numbers with the x=int part which is (if x==1, if x==2), but then I'm trying to use letters for the letters options, and getting the errors.

My Code:

```
`
import pandas as pd             
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

print("****Welcome to the python data analysis app****")

x=int(input("Please enter file you wish to review:\n 1. Population Data\n 2. Housing Data\n 3. Exit 
the program\n "))


if x==1:
  print("You have entered Population Data.")

  y=str(input("Select the Column you want to analyze:\n a. Pop Apr 1\n b. Pop Jul 1\n c. Change Pop\n 
  d. Exit Column\n"))

  if y==a: 
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv") 
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Pop Apr 1"]]
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show() 
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y==b:
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv") 
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Pop Jul 1"]] 
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show()
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y==c:
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv")
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Change Pop"]]
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show()
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y==d:
    x=int() 


if x==2:
  housing=pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")
  housing_selected=housing[["AGE", "BEDRMS", "BUILT", "ROOMS", "UTILITY"]]
  housing_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15))
  plt.show()
  print(housing_selected.describe())
`
```

Error Message:

```
File "main.py", line 13, in <module>

if y==a: 

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: `a` in your code is without quotes, so interpreter expects it to be a variable handle, but it is in fact supposed to be a string literal. Just enclose in quotes and do the same with other choices too.

Comment: also it'd be better to use `elif` to short-circuit after one is already matched

Comment: Where at in the code are you saying I need to enclose a in quotes? @pavel

Comment: You need to have `y=="a"`, `y=="b"`, etc.

Comment: Okay thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Maybe you meant `'a'` (string) in which case you should wrap it in quotes.

E.g.

```
  if y=='a':  # string literal
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv") 
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Pop Apr 1"]]
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show() 
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y=='b':
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv") 
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Pop Jul 1"]] 
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show()
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y=='c':
    popchange=pd.read_csv("PopChange.csv")
    popchange_selected = popchange[["Change Pop"]]
    popchange_selected.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
    plt.show()
    print(popchange_selected.describe())

  if y=='d':
    x=int()
```